# Spark GraphX subgraph method generate null.

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I use `subgraph` to filter the graph vertices.
However when I collect the vertices, some `null` value are in there.

I can guarantee that the original graph vertices contains no `null` value.

```
class A ....
val graph = .... // no null value contained
val selected_id:Set[Int] = SomeAlgorithm collect() toSet

val sub = graph.subgraph(vpred = (id,data) => data match {
    case x:A => selected_id contains x.id
    case _ => true
  })


sub.vertices.map(_._2).collect() filter (_ == null) foreach println //null printed out
```